# Lisp function adding odd numbers from a subset

Tags: numbers, lisp, addition, subset

I need to define a function in Common Lisp that would sum all odd integers from the set of integers from `a` to `b`. For example, for the subset from 2 to 8 the result would be 15, sum of 3, 5, and 7. Any suggestions?

I do have something like this, where a is the beginning of a set and b is the end of it.

```
(defun add (a b)
  (if(and(< a x) (> b x))
    (if(even(x))
        ((setq ( x (+a 1))) (+ x 2))
        ((setq(x a)) (+ x 2))
            )))
```

EDIT:

```
(defun add (a b)
  (if(and(< a x) (> b x))
    (if(evenp x))
        ((setq ( x (+a 1))
            (loop for x from a to b do (+ x 2))))
        ((setq(x a)) (+ x 2)
            (loop for x from a to b do (+ x 2)))
                ))
```

(I use CLISP implementation)

Comment: Start with the first odd number at or equal to the start of the range, loop adding 2 and adding them all to the total, until you get past the end of the range.

Comment: well, i get how the algorithm should be working, i just don't know how to implement it in lisp

Comment: Show what you've tried, we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I have got it it shown

Comment: You seem to have problems with basic Lisp syntax, e.g. `(even(x))` should be `(even x)`. You also don't have a loop in your code. Where are you setting `x`?

Comment: If `a` or `b` are odd, should they be added to sum?  That is, are `a` and `b` inclusive or exclusive range markers?

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way to do this is with `LOOP`.  The `LOOP` solution is very straightforward:

```
(defun sum-odds (start end)
  (loop for i from start to end 
        when (oddp i) sum i))

(sum-odds 2 8)
=> 15
```

For iteration, you could also use `DO`, but you have to be a bit more explicit about how everything works (and you have many more options):

```
(defun sum-odds2 (begin end)
  (do ((sum 0)
       (i begin (1+ i)))
      ((= i end) sum)
    (when (oddp i)
      (incf sum i))))

(sum-odds2 2 8)
=> 15
```

If you do use a solution that creates a list containing the range of integers (which creates a bunch of intermediate lists to be garbage collected), as suggested in some other answers, you should consider how many times you traverse that list (there's no reason to traverse it more than once).  You can use `REDUCE` to sum the elements of the list with a `:key` argument that makes odd numbers look like themselves, and even numbers look like `0`:

```
(defun sum-odds3 (list)
  (reduce '+ list
          :key (lambda (n)
                 (if (oddp n)
                   n
                   0))))

(sum-odds3 '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
=> 15
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to do my usual shtick and put on the code-review hat, but having properly formatted your second attempt, there are too many problems here to take an incremental approach. You need to sit down and explain what you intended this code to do.

Specifically, what's going on with `x`? Is that meant to be a global binding that you're re-setting each time, or did you mean to define a local binding and accidentally forgot that both the `if`s need the variable before you get around to it? What are you trying to do with those `setq`s, and what are you trying to do with those `loops` (as written, neither do anything)?

---

[temporarily dons code-review hat]

First up, kindly [format your code properly](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html). It's a small thing, but it increases readability by quite a bit.

```
(defun add (a b)
  (if (and (< a x) (> b x))
     (if (evenp x))
     ((setq (x (+ a 1))
            (loop for x from a to b do (+ x 2))))
     ((setq (x a)) (+ x 2)
      (loop for x from a to b do (+ x 2)))))
```

---

And with the proper indentation level, quite a few errors just fall out at you right away.

- First off, that top `if` has three clauses in it (the `if` and two `setq`s for some reason).
- Second, that second `if` has no clauses, just a test. Which means it does nothing
- Third, you're calling some very oddly named functions in the `if` body. I'm willing to guarantee that `((setq (x a)) (+ x 2) (loop for x from a to b do (+ x 2)))` isn't what you mean, because that's calling the function `(setq (x a))` on the arguments `(+ x 2)` and `(loop ...)`.
- Fourth, you invoke `setq` in two different incorrect ways. `(setq (x (+ a 1))` this is attempting to set the result of calling the function `x` on `(+ a 1)` to `NIL`. `(setq (x a)) (+ x 2)` this is trying to set the result of calling the function `x` on `a` to `NIL`, then evaluating and discarding `(+ x 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see it is to use applicative programming.

```
    (defun range (max &key (min 0) (step 1))
      (loop for n from min below max by step
        collect n))
```

You can use the range function to generate your interval like this:

```
    (range 8 :min 2) => (2 3 4 5 6 7)
```

and then filter with remove-if-not:

```
    (remove-if-not #'oddp (range 8 :min 2)) => (3 5 7)
```

and apply addition to the result:

```
    (apply #'+ (remove-if-not #'oddp (range 8 :min 2))) => 15
```

You can wrap the above in a function too:

```
    (defun add (a b)
      (apply #'+ (remove-if-not #'oddp (range b :min a))))
```

Comment: Don't use APPLY, use REDUCE.

Comment: The use of RANGE is not so good in Common Lisp, since it actually creates the whole list. In a lazy language, this might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not yet facing an algorithmic problem until you have fixed the syntactic problems.  You apparently have guessed at a solution and have yet to even compile your guess.  Your code won't compile and won't run.  You are studying Lisp-like languages precisely because they allow for trivial exploration.  So explore.

```
(defun add (a b)
  (cond ((evenp a) (add (+ a 1) b))
        ((> a b)   0)
        (t         (+ a (add (+ a 2) b)))))
```